# Jobdsl code for scan by webhook in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a multipipeline job in Jenkins and I have enabled the functionality of scan multibranch Pipeline trigger via the help of "scan by webhook" please refer the picture below. can anyone help me with the jobdsl code?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this with help below Job DSL code

```
configure { node ->
  def webhookTrigger = node / triggers / 'com.igalg.jenkins.plugins.mswt.trigger.ComputedFolderWebHookTrigger' {
    spec('')
    token("test-multibranch")
  }
}
```